# ARC and 'strong' setters

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Consider:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel * label ;
@end
```

and:

```
@implementation MyView
@synthesize label ;
- (void) setLabel: (UILabel *) label_ {
    self->label = label_ ;
    // ... custom stuff for when the label is changed from the outside
}
@end
```

Ideally, what I want is to 'trap' the default synthetized setter so that it 'does the right thing' under ARC, and would only add what I need to, in order to 'update' my context with this new label.

I am worried that the line:

```
self->label = label_ ;
```

just bypasses whatever invariant the default synthesized setter would have guaranteed had I not chosen to provide my own.

What is the proper way to 'override' the the default synthesized setter under ARC?

Comment: Your setter is fine. You're not the first to wish there was a way to invoke the would-be-synthesized logic before or after doing custom stuff, but there's no language support for that. But with ARC, the would-be-synthesized logic is really reduced to a simple assignment as jrturton mentions. (It is necessary to declare the property `nonatomic` as you've done, though, if you're only providing one side of the getter/setter pair.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ARC the default setter would just be:

```
label = label_;
```

Though if you're going to use underscores you might as well use the underscored name as the backing ivar, so:

```
@synthesize label = label_;
```

And:

```
- (void) setLabel: (UILabel *) label{
    label_ = label;
    // ... custom stuff for when the label is changed from the outside
}
```

This is a pretty typical overridden accessor.

Comment: Convention is to have the underscores at the beginning of ivars. This is how it will be implemented in Xcode 4.4's automatic @synthesize.

Comment: So I hear. At the moment, though, I prefer the google style (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Variable_Names) since you'll never clash with an internal apple ivar.

Comment: You'll never clash with an Apple ivar anyway on the modern runtime (iOS, 64-bit OS X), as it mangles ivar names with the class name.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Do you have a reference for that? It does annoy me using trailing underscores since it doesn't autocomplete for you.

Comment: If you have access to Apple's dev forums, see the discussion surrounding the default @synthesize feature: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/141669?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I propose an alternative. You setup yourself as an observer to changes to label property and do your extra stuff in the method you pass on as your selector. It's more modular and less likely to break things.

Comment: This would make it more complicated than it has to be. What if you wanted to change some properties of the object that was passed in?

Comment: Can you bring an example? It's a matter of style I guess, but changing anything else than current object's properties sounds like too tight coupling.